# makefile/script for small program

Tags: c++, makefile

I have to frequently compile small program and run it. Since, it was tedious to write compile command  `g++ -W -Wall file.cpp -o out` everytime for each cpp file, I wrote one small scripts, which does the compiling.

Here is the script that I wrote

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -W -Wall $1 -o $1.out
```

So, if I have to compile file.cpp, I will do `compile file.cpp`  and it will create `file.cpp.out` executable for me. 
And, such file.cpp dont have any header files or any other dependencies.

I know how to write makefile for particular file.cpp like this (very simple case)

```
file: file.cpp
    g++ -W -Wall file.cpp -o file
```

but if I have to compile file2.cpp, I have to change above makefile again or write new. So, what I want to do is, when I give `make file.cpp` command it will produce file as executable. And when I give  `make file2.cpp` it will produce file2 as executable, and similarly for other cpp files.

Comment: Please do not try to use HTML tags to format your code. Simply hilight the code and then hit Ctrl-K.

Comment: @Neil: I will do that from now onwards. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
export CXXFLAGS="-W -Wall"
rm Makefile
make file1
```

Make has sane defaults. You don't have to write a makefile to use make.

Make has a set of generic rules, which get apply automatically when there is no specific rule. One of them is to make 'file' out of 'file.cpp' using a C++ compiler with flags from environment variable CXXFLAGS. This works a bit like you want...

Comment: The only problem with that is it relies on the environment being the same each time. Sometimes when the environment changes (like between two seassions) unexpected results can be hard to diagnose. I prefer to just create a Makefile with the flags defined inside. Then I know exactly how the objects are built. (Think of it like build documentation and we know documentation is good).

Answer (score 4):

You can have the following target

```
.cpp:
        g++ -W -Wall $@.cpp -o $@
```

This creates an implicit rule which means that to generate file named `x` where a file `x.cpp` already exists, perform the following operation.

When you have the rule, you can just do this from command line:

```
make file
make file2
```

Answer (score 3):

Relying on make's default rules for C++, the makefile only needs

```
CPPFLAGS ?= -W -Wall
```

Then at the command line:

```
make file1
make file2
rm file2
make file2 CPPFLAGS="-W -Wall -O3"
rm file2
make file2 CXXFLAGS="-O3"   # possibly a bit too cunning, this one
                            # It has the same effect as the one with CPPFLAGS
```

Personally, I would add to the makefile

```
EXECUTABLES = file1 file2

all: $(EXECUTABLES)

clean: 
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLES)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%: %.cpp
    g++ -W -Wall $*.cpp -o $*
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a Makefile with the following line

```
CXXFLAGS=-W -Wall
```

You can now call e.g.

```
make foo
```

and it'll automatically look for a "foo.cpp" file.

Answer (score 0):

A `Makefile` doesn't intend to work as a script; taking particular inputs to generate particular outputs. It, instead, describes dependencies between files, and how to build any dependency, in order to reach a particular target.

Although it is possible to do what you are asking for by creating a target called "file1" and a target called "file2", that's not the idea behind `Makefile`s; you might be better using a shell script if this is your requirement.

Comment: -1: `Makefile` is a build system to control generating executables, whether is simple case or complex.  It is meant to handle cases as simple as this, and it is superior to shell scripts.

Comment: Sinan is right, though.  Make is not a scripting language--it's a declarative language to specify dependencies between files in order to create products.  It is neither superior nor inferior to shell scripts (which is an imperative/procedural language); they are complementary technologies.  Trying to use make as a scripting language generally comes out bad.

Comment: It's true that using make as a general-purpose scripting language is hard, but the OP didn't propose that, he proposed replacing a trivial script that called g++, with a makefile. It's false that creating a make target called "file1" and another called "file2", when those are the names of the files you want to build, is "not the idea behind makefiles". It's exactly the idea behind makefiles. In this case you'd use the same rule for the two targets, of course.

Comment: Makefile is superior to shell scripts in doing its job, namely "building and generating executables."  Using `make` to do general-purpose scripting is bad style.

Comment: Actually, make has one key advantage for general-purpose scripting, that it's trivial to write code which can fail (or be interrupted) and then pick up where it left off. If your "script" is actually just a list of commands, not using loops or modifying variables as it goes, then IMO a makefile with a single target can have the edge over bash. But I still don't advocate it as the first place to go for *nix scripting. That's what find is for ;-) http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~pmaydell/find/

Answer (score 0):

You can run **make** prog# to build the appropriate program.

```
CXX=/usr/bin/g++
CXXFLAGS=-W -Wall
TARGETS=prog1 prog2 prog3

all: $(TARGETS)

prog1: prog1.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) prog1.cpp -o prog1

prog2: prog2.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) prog2.cpp -o prog2

prog3: prog3.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) prog3.cpp -o prog3
```